# Regex repeating string

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex for the following text.
I already tried many stuff, but always it only match the last two groups or it match 'someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 &' as one group...

```
someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3
someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4
```

What I expect are two matches:

Match 1:

- someText 1
- someText 2
- someText 3

and

Match 2:

- someText 1
- someText 2
- someText 3
- someText 4

Comment: What attempts have you made? If any, please provide so you can have further help. Also what kind of characters, etc are possibly in `someText`?

Comment: What runtime are you using? Is this JavaScript, Python, .NET, Java, Ruby, something else? We need to know so we can test the results.

Comment: Sorry i deleted the regex already, because they dont work..
@jpmc26 Python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should indicate which host language you're using the regexes with.  You should also show your best effort so far — what have you tried?  Or a couple of them.  Can you invoke the regex iteratively over the string containing the data, or must it be a single pattern?  Would your code be able to handle missing fields.  Could there be fewer than 3 or more than 4 sets of data?

Comment: Are you using a regex because this is homework?  Because if you have a string with delimiters, I'd think you would just want to split it on the delimiters rather than use a regex...

Comment: I deleted already any Regex...
As Example, i dont understand why this not work:
^(?:(.*) & )+(.*)$
I have a row with one group where is any thing AND ' & ' and this exists one or more times...
The last group is the someText without & at the end

Alternative : ^(?:(.*)( & )?)+$

Comment: @hwnd
You have just 1 Match..
I want something like :
[
   ['someText 1', 'someText 2', 'someText 3'],
   ['someText 1', 'someText 2', 'someText 3', 'someText 4']
]

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading properly, you're trying to capture an arbitrary number of '&' separated items, per line, into capture groups.

With pure regex, this isn't possible. Because regex operates as a state machine, you cannot have an arbitrary number of capture groups. Any given expression has a fixed number of capture groups which may or may capture anything. The number is determined by the expression (basically, how many sets of parenthesis you have) and cannot change.

Instead, you can do something similar capturing the delimiter instead. So, instead of trying to match "someText 3", match and split on "&".

I don't know what language you're using, so here's some example code in Javascript:

```
// Test input, as provided.
var inputString = "someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3\nsomeText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4";

// Break up the lines. (Replace this with however you get your lines separated.)
var line_delimit = /[\n\r]+/;
var lines = inputString.split(line_delimit);

// Split each line on ampersands.
var group_delimit = /\s*&\s*/;
var matches = [];
lines.forEach(function(line){
    matches.push(line.split(group_delimit));
});

// Display.
for (var index in matches){
    console.log("Match " + index + ":");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(matches[index],null,2));
    console.log();
}
```

Comment: I agree with "With pure regex, this isn't possible".  The OP is using Python (see their first comment on the question — and the tag I added in light of that comment).

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice the Python tag. Alas, I don't know Python either, so hopefully my JS will help, at least. If someone would like to re-write it as Python, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the provided example text and desired results:

```
\S+\s\d

\S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
\d match a digit [0-9]
```

Comment: Its an Example instead of 'someText 1' the can also 'fagSDGar23132!"§$ 1'

Comment: @False You should clarify in your question that the "text" can vary, and you should also clarify what symbols it can contain. These are *extremely* important aspects when it comes to pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think [James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754545/1394393) is on to something, but he didn't quite get there.

You shouldn't try to do this with pure regex. Keep things simple. First, you should just split your string by `&`:

```
>>> s = 'someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4'
>>> s.split('&')
['someText 1 ', ' someText 2 ', ' someText 3 ', ' someText 4']
```

(This of course assumes that `someText` can't contain `&`, but you have a *much* more difficult problem if it can.)

Then we need to `strip` off the leading and trailing whitespace:

```
>>> s_clean = [i.strip() for i in s.split('&')]
>>> s_clean
['someText 1', 'someText 2', 'someText 3', 'someText 4']
```

Now we can use regular expressions to filter out the elements that don't match:

```
>>> import re
>>> [i for i in s_clean if re.match('.+\s+[0-9]+', i)]
['someText 1', 'someText 2', 'someText 3', 'someText 4']
```

(Note that `re.match` actually returns a `Match` object, not a boolean.)

This gives what you want. To shorten it up:

```
s = 'someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4'
s_clean = [i.strip() for i in s.split('&')]
result = [i for i in s_clean if re.match('.+\s+[0-9]+', i)]
```

You could turn this into a one-liner if you want, but it'll be even more messy looking.

Now repeat the following line 3 times to yourself:

> Regex is not the go to solution for all text processing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Python, you need the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module and the `re.findall` method.

For example, you might use:

```
import re
import fileinput

p1 = re.compile(r'\s*(\S[^&]*)\s+(&|$)')

for line in fileinput.input():
    matches = p1.findall(line)
    print "Line: ", line
    for match in matches:
        print "Match: ", match
    print ""
```

The regex looks for optional white space (`\s*`), then captures a non-white space followed by zero or more non-ampersands (`(\S[^&]*)`) followed by white space and either `&` or end of string (`\s+(&|$)`).

Given input containing the two sample lines you show in the question:

```
someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3
someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4
```

the output is:

```
Line:  someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3

Match:  ('someText 1', '&')
Match:  ('someText 2', '&')
Match:  ('someText 3', '')

Line:  someText 1 & someText 2 & someText 3 & someText 4

Match:  ('someText 1', '&')
Match:  ('someText 2', '&')
Match:  ('someText 3', '&')
Match:  ('someText 4', '')
```

There are endless tweaks that could be applied, such as using `(?:&|$)` so there's only one capture group — the output is then just the '`someText N`' strings.  You might also use a non-greedy match `[^&]*?` though it works OK as written.  If there were adjacent `&` characters, the second would be treated as the not-white-space at the start of the next string.  You can fix that if you think it might be a real problem.